# Moving up directory to access file not using raw path in Python

Tags: python-3.x, directory, selenium-chromedriver

I have a project named `testrequest` and I am working on a file named `test_function_pack.py`. The working code within the said file is below:

```
service = Service(r'C:\user\Dev\Selenium\testrequest\drivers\chromedriver.exe')
```

I wish to try accessing the chromedriver.exe file using `..` or `.` dots and by my understanding, the distance of the two file is two directories upward. I tested using the below code

```
import os
os.chdir('..')
service = Service(r'../../drivers/chromedriver.exe')
```

But the code above does not work, am I missing anything here? Any help is appreciated.

Here is the folder by the way:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65333932/9928905 You can use this piece of code by that you can automate the process of configuring the chromedriver to the latest version

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this should work.

```
import os
stepups = 2
a = '/'.join(os.path.dirname(__file__).split('\\')[:stepups]) + '/drivers/chromedriver.exe'
print(a)
```

Do your own work regarding the step-ups you require, and change that accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, in my case I need to set my `stepups` to 5 to achieve the correct path. It's amazing that it is able to navigate to the right folder.

Comment: Glad I could help!